# How to set alias for Grafana Query with Prometheus Input

Tags: grafana, prometheus

I am currently facing an issue with Grafana/Prometheus. 
I've got a [panel](https://grafana.net/plugins/vonage-status-panel) and I am trying to add different queries to it. To be able to configure thresholds I should give every query a unique alias but I really don't know how to do that.

Could anybody provide an example to me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this link http://docs.grafana.org/features/datasources/prometheus/#templated-queries

To use Template Query is help for you.

First, you should define label_values with metric or not. and, extract what you want in your panel.

[image]

[image]

this is my dashboard. 
I have imported [Node Exporter Server metrics](https://grafana.net/dashboards/405), and modify 'instance' to 'alias' in Template Query. I hope this will help you.