# Add labels to gauge panel in Grafana

Tags: grafana

This is probably a trivial question, I'm just starting on Grafana.  I've got a query that's producing a gauge output from multiple instances, I'd like to have a single gauge panel that can display a different gauge for each source.  Essentially, I'm returning data like this

```
value{instance="server1"} 9
value{instance="server2"} 10
value{instance="server3"} 5
```

I can put this into a gauge panel, and three gauges appear with the correct values.  Perfect.  But I can't find a way to label the gauges to know that `server1` is displaying 9 rather than `server3`.  Am I missing something super simple?

[image]

Grafana 6.1.6

**UPDATE:** As of grafana 6.2.1, labels are now supported on gauge panels!  Thanks guys!

Comment: I think you should find a response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42020008/how-to-set-alias-for-grafana-query-with-prometheus-input)

Comment: I don't think that helps (though I could be misunderstanding).  My problem is I can't get ANY label (or legend) to display on the gauge.  Edited to add screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I understand. So,that is not possible to display multiple labels for this type of panel in grafana. 
The only legend possibly working is to set a "prefix" but you can only set one for all your gauges.

[image]

I'm using Graphite but it's the same for prometheus, and i have to do that :

[image]

Reconsiders to separate them into 3 differents panels.
Hope it'll help you.

Comment: I was afraid that was the answer...  unfortunately, it was a simplified use case and there are actually closer to 20 servers we'd like monitored in the same panel.  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Opened this as a feature request: https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/16960